# Push custom profiles to Scratch org using Salesforce CLI

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, custom-profile

I pushed custom profiles to scratch org from my dev org. But permissions of profile were not set in scratch org. I want my scratch org profiles to look exactly same as in my developer org. Please let me know the way to do it.